# Async Report Run Never Finishes

Tags: reporting, reports-api

I have some code that creates a report instance using the REST API and then waits for the report to run in order to get the data.

For most cases, this code works well.  But I have one case for a particular customer where the asynchronous execution seems to never finish.  Usually it takes 3-5 minutes.  But in this particular case, I've been waiting for over 2 hours and the report is still showing 'status="Running"'.  Any ideas what's happening?

I don't have much visibility into the customers SF instance.  I just have access to the reporting API and the report id.

The code is basic ruby code and is doing something like this:

```
instance_response = post "/services/data/v36/analytics/reports/#{report_id}/instances", body, params
status_url = instance_response["url"]

loop do
  response = get status_url
  return if response.attributes.status == "Success"
end
```

As I mentioned, this works for all my other customers except for the one outlier.  The report contains a handful of columns and has just over 7,000 rows.

Comment: I thought analytics api [was limited to 2000 rows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_limits_limitations.htm)

Comment: It is limited to 2,000 rows, but there are some ways to get around that.  Specifically, if your report contains an ID column, you can sort by that column, and then make subsequent requests using something like 'lead_id > [last_id_from_current_page]'.  That aside, I can't even get the first page of 2,000 results to finish.

Comment: what happens if you run the REST request from SFDC Workbench?

Comment: I'm running this on behalf of a customer, so I don't have their credentials to login to the workbench.  But they are able to run the report inside of SF, and have exported it to .xlsx to show that it is working.

Comment: I'm not convinced that reports run within the SFDC UI have the same limits as when run from the Analytics API.  You could get client to try the query in Workbench (use gotomeeting or its ilk) to assist